# How to add the regression coefiicents and their p-values in heatmap in R

Tags: r, regression, heatmap, p-value

I have a CSV file that contains the regression coefficients with their p-values for 5 variables and I want to plot a heatmap in R for those variables and adding the p-values for each variable in my heatmap. I got the heatmap with the coefficients values on it but I don't know how to add the p-values on the same heatmap for each cell.

Here are the code lines that I used to create the heatmap:

```
heat_map = read.csv("data.csv",header=TRUE) 
heat_map <- data.matrix(heat_map)

heatmap.2(heat_map, trace="none", margins=c(8,10), keysize=1, Rowv=NULL, Colv=NULL,
          scale="none",col=greenred(75) ,cexRow=1.5,cexCol=1.5,cellnote = heat_map,
          notecol = "white",density.info = "none",main = "main")


var1    Pv_var1 var2    Pv_var2 var3    Pv_var3 var4    Pv_var4 var5    Pv_var5
A1  0.0190984   0.02357 -0.0281088  0.000401    0.003468    0.5143  -0.0008918  0.88302 -0.007152   0.263496
A2  0.0221705   0.86671 0.0076612   0.950872    0.005768    0.9448  -0.0867437  0.36075 0.213846    0.03279
A3  0.0495224   0.00485 0.0001063   0.994877    -0.022855   0.0392  0.0080875   0.522   0.002015    0.879875
A4  -0.0241206  0.0794  0.0131758   0.308709    -0.018969   0.0287  -0.0184561  0.06176 0.025268    0.01539
A5  0.0043308   0.76839 -0.0138724  0.316327    0.005807    0.5311  -0.0169831  0.10803 0.01172 0.293334
A6  -0.0340032  0.00167 0.0454484   8.11E-06    -0.001621   0.812   -0.0015225  0.84467 0.006245    0.446413
A7  0.2228737   0.01882 -0.1223063  0.170832    -0.032831   0.583   -0.0169071  0.8041  -0.011615   0.871737
A8  -0.0168572  0.82622 0.0862938   0.232513    -0.011987   0.8044  -0.0345139  0.53157 0.012012    0.836548
A9  0.0166566   0.81513 0.0230153   0.731453    -0.006176   0.8906  -0.0426715  0.40449 -0.020101   0.709833
A10 0.0396111   0.01163 0.0035166   0.811897    -0.019428   0.0496  0.0088384   0.43327 -0.002297   0.847008
A11 0.0926558   0.03327 -0.0634824  0.121263    -0.016146   0.5562  -0.0122736  0.69469 -0.003489   0.915807
A12 -0.0477884  6.98E-06    0.0789409   3.28E-15    -0.039443   4.05E-09    0.0235915   0.00201 0.028165    0.000477
A13 0.0450669   0.00221 -0.0167163  0.227814    0.004254    0.6467  0.0005154   0.96114 -0.012946   0.246277
A14 0.1393946   0.35641 0.0532552   0.708191    -0.083229   0.3824  0.0232611   0.8304  0.008315    0.942171
A15 -0.0193469  0.07151 -0.00202    0.841557    0.007636    0.2592  0.0067711   0.38    0.005511    0.498412
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For the R tag we share data using `dput()` (see the R tag description). Please edit the question to remove the screenshot and replace it with a `dput()` of your data.

Comment: A heatmap is a color encoded display of a single column mapped along two dimensions. Your request doesn't make sense. Please step back a couple of paces and explain in more detail what you wnat to see happen. Saying "add p-values to the coefficient map" really is not enough.